# How to install ubuntu on separated flash drives?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I need to install a single version of Ubuntu on 2 USB flash drives, what is the best partitioning scheme to use for this situation? All I want to do on the flash drives are play minecraft, and use for minimal everyday things.

The current on I want to use is

/dev/sda = / 8 GB  (My root)

/dev/sdb = /usr 8 GB (For my programs to install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to play Minecraft and browse the web, this partitioning will do:

```
/dev/sda = /
/dev/sdb = unused
```

Alternatively, you could make a [RAID 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID-1#RAID_1) volume of the two disks to protect against the failure of one drive. A RAID 1 volume uses two (or more) disks with identical contents, so if one disk fails, you still have a working system. Or you could use the second drive to back up your data.

Separating `/usr` is not useful. On a typical desktop machine, `/usr` makes up the bulk of what is not `/home`. If you have little data on `/home`, with your scheme, you'd end up with `/dev/sda` almost empty. If you have a lot of data in `/home`, make *it* `/dev/sdb`.

If you need more than 8GB for the system, there's no particularly meaningful place to break it up. `/usr/lib` would be a good bet. Anyway, you can mount `/dev/sdb` wherever you like, and move one or more directories there and create a symbolic link.

Rather than pick a mount point, there's a simpler approach to splitting your system between two drives: **make it a [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_0#RAID_0) volume**. RAID 0 combines two or more disks into one, in an arrangement that tries to spread the load evenly between the disks. The advantages of RAID 0 over a mount point is that you don't have to worry at all about choosing the mount point right for splitting the space evenly, and that it's a bit faster. The downside of RAID 0 is that if one of the disks fails, the whole filesystem will be unusable.

To install Ubuntu on a RAID volume, you'll need to use the server (alternate) installation media and do manual partitioning.

Comment: i've done that partition map before and i ran out of room, i'll be install a few programs to make ubuntu "more convenient". i'll be using at least 9gb total

Comment: i wont have too much stuff on /home, just maybe 1.5gb-2gb

Comment: @user146881 If you need more than 8GB outside `/home` then the simplest by far is to install as RAID 0. See my edit.